# Scope of for loop variable in jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is some code referring to a form

```
$form.submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var fields = ['id', 'name', 'subject', 'theory', 'practical']; //?
        var record = {};

        for (var index in fields) {

            var field = fields[index];

            if (field == 'id' || field == 'theory' || field == 'practical')
                record[field] = parseInt( $('input#'+field).val() );

            else
                record[field] = $('input#'+field).val();

        }
```

/*
Now at this position if i initialize a $.ajax method and inside that I create a for loop again like this

```
for (var field in record) {

                            if (field == 'id')
                                continue;
```

Is the field here same as the field above??

*/
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the field here same as the field above?

Yes, with `var` it is. It wouldn't be with `let` in ES2015, but it is with `var`, because `var` anywhere in the function has function scope and declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the function they're in.

If we add that loop, we get this:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var fields = ['id', 'name', 'subject', 'theory', 'practical']; //?
    var record = {};

    for (var index in fields) {

        var field = fields[index];

        if (field == 'id' || field == 'theory' || field == 'practical')
            record[field] = parseInt($('input#' + field).val());

        else
            record[field] = $('input#' + field).val();

    }
    for (var field in record) {

        if (field == 'id')
            continue;
    }
});
```

which is processed exactly as though it were this:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    // All of the variables are declared before step-by-step code runs
    var fields;
    var record;
    var index;
    var field;

    e.preventDefault();

    fields = ['id', 'name', 'subject', 'theory', 'practical']; //?
    record = {};

    for (index in fields) {

        field = fields[index];

        if (field == 'id' || field == 'theory' || field == 'practical')
            record[field] = parseInt($('input#' + field).val());

        else
            record[field] = $('input#' + field).val();

    }
    for (field in record) {

        if (field == 'id')
            continue;
    }
});
```

That would **not** be true if you were using `let`. With `let`, variables are block-scoped and only partially hoisted.